# Which columns to index in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT ID,uye,kazanilacakmiktar FROM kupon WHERE durum=0 AND ID IN (
select c.kupon
from kuponbahis c join
     bahis b 
     on ((b.sonuc = c.secim) OR (b.sonuc=5)) and b.ID = c.bahis 
group by c.kupon
having sum(c.bahis = '999') > 0 and
       count(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kuponbahis WHERE kupon = c.kupon));
```

I have a query like this. I have indexes at `kupon.ID, kupon.uye, kupon.kazanilacakmiktar, kuponbahis.bahis, kuponbahis.secim` but it still has a significant runtime.

What I'm missing, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to ask another question with sample data and desired results.  There might be a better way to write the query.

Comment: You'll have more acurate responses if you write everything in plain English... ie kupon => coupon . It's much easier to understand. You'll want to add more info as well -list all indices with all fields and uniqueness, and the numbers of rows of each table.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious indexes for the query are:

- `kupon(durum, id)`
- `kuponbahis(kupon)`
- `bahis(id, sonuc)`

However, I'm not convinced that these indexes will be a big help for t his query  The query is rather complicated and there may be alternative ways of expressing the logic.